# Angular set focus to dialog box on load

Tags: angular, accessibility

I am trying to set initial focus on load to the dialog box. Using dialog box component in various other component. Wherever we are using it, I am trying to set initial focus to dialog box. Please check my code below and give your suggestions what I am doing wrong here

```
<div role="dialog" #dialog1  aria-labelledby="dialog1_label" tabindex="0" aria-modal="true">
<ng-content select="popup-header" id="dialog1_label"></ng-content>
...................................
</div>
```

On ts side I have this

```
export class PopupComponent  {
  @ViewChild('dialog1') dialog1: ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dialog1.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

I am not able to have intitial focus on load to dialog box, I have set focus on dialog box after ngOnit too but its not working. We are not using angular materials so can't use `cdkFocusInitial`

Comment: Why would you `focus` a div?

Comment: I wanted to focus on whole dialog box, so added the dialog box parts under div and set focus on div

Comment: Note that **@angular/cdk** is not the same as **@angular/material**. Angular CDK contains tons of awesome utilities, like `CdkTrapFocus`, `Overlay`, `CdkDragDrop`, Virtual Scrolling, ... They're used by but not bound to angular material

Comment: So you want to focus the first element in the dialog when the dialog is shown? I created a [`FocusOnLoadDirective`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-focus-on-load/src/lib/directives/focus-on-load/focus-on-load.directive.ts) that focuses the element when it's inserted in the DOM in any way. However it won't work on elements that are shown/hidden

Comment: We have conditional dialog box, on component load, based on specific conditions, it will show the dialog box, on click of cancel button on dialog box, it will close it. 
CdkTrapFocus is part of Angular ? not angular material? Sorry, I am back to angular after 3 years

Comment: [`FocusTrap`](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src%2Fcdk%2Fa11y%2Ffocus-trap) is available by installing angular CDK (`npm i @angular/cdk`). It prevents the user from [tabbing outside of a component](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/additional-samples/focus-trap) when something (like a dialog box) is shown in overlay. @angular/cdk is by default not included in an angular project, but can be installed using before-mentioned command

Comment: Get compatibility issues now, installed andular/cdk version:10,11 for angular 11. but still issue persisits

Comment: Obviously the angular cdk major version must be the same as the angular version. You can simply open the **package.json**, add `"@angular/cdk": "~xx.0.0"` to dependencies manually, and run `npm i`. Where `xx` is the major angular version you're using. Should work.

Comment: And the [autofocus directive](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-focus-on-load/src/lib/directives/focus-on-load/focus-on-load.directive.ts) I mentioned is something I've written myself. You can either copy it over, or install it with `npm i @mintplayer/ng-focus-on-load`. Import the `FocusOnLoadModule`, and apply the `autofocus` attribute to an input or angular component...

Comment: Enclosed in a setTime:`setTimeout(()=>{this.dialog1.nativeElement.focus();})`. This give Angular time to paint the component. Really makes that check again the app -it's the same than use ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()-